# Is there a word (or shorter/clearer phrase) for "incorrect implication/suggestion"?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, vocabulary, logic

Example sentences:

- I don't drink bleach very often.
- Why does one plus one equal three?

The first sentence seems to suggest that I do drink bleach *occasionally*, even though from a strictly logically perspective, "never" drinking bleach meets the criteria of "not very often" too.

The second sentence can't be answered because it presumes that 1+1=3.

Maybe the two sentences don't have the same sort of problem, but in either case, I'm wondering if there is a word for describing these sort of misleading statements.

Comment: Single word requests must have an example sentence showing how the word will be used. A large part of this is so that we can know whether you're looking for an adjective or a noun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that popped into my head was *non sequitur*—except that doesn't actually apply.

After consideration, I think those sentences are good examples of [**double-talk**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/double-talk):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **1** : language that appears to be earnest and meaningful but in fact is a mixture of sense and nonsense

While it's possible that somebody actually *does* drink bleach on occasion, a more natural interpretation is that the question is being asked as a kind of "put on", and is an example of something that only sounds meaningful at first.

Answer (score 1):

The first one about drinking bleach could be seen as an:

equivocation

> equivocate
>  vb
>  (intr) to use vague or ambiguous language, esp
>   in order to avoid speaking directly or honestly
>  [Collins English
>   Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/equivocate)

Even if it's not said for deceptive means, the statement can still be equivocal:

> equivocal
>  adj
>   1. capable of varying interpretations; ambiguous
>  [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/equivocal)

Although from an English pragmatics point of view to say such a thing would likely be understood they drink at least some bleach.

Another example similar to this is the line from comedian Mitch Hedberg:

> "I used to do drugs."

Having the implication that he used to do drugs but doesn't anymore. If you watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ndBjraV-3UY) you'll see it's clearly an intentionally misleading opening set up to deliver the punchline.

As to the second example about 1 plus 1 equalling 3, Lawrence's answer I believe is correct. It can also be seen as "begging the question."

> 2. To assume or believe that something is true when its veracity is unverified. My opponent in this debate has again begged the question,
>      assuming his premise to be true without evidence.
>     [idiom at The
>      Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/beg+the+question)

Although as the claim does seem to be a premise, and it is clearly false, then Lawrence's answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You might be reaching for the term "false premise".

> A **false premise** is an incorrect proposition that forms the basis of an argument or syllogism. Since the premise (proposition, or assumption) is not correct, the conclusion drawn may be in error.
>   [- wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_premise)

However, this term is more applicable to the context of *logical reasoning* than to misleading statements on their own.

Addressing your examples individually:

- Your *bleach* example might be simply termed a *misleading statement*. The statement strongly suggests the 'sometimes' interpretation even though it may be incorrect and not necessarily required by the statement.
- The *sums* example is simply a question built on faulty assumptions.